# Unable to get a WinTV-HVR-5525 running under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, tv-tuner

I just got a WinTV-HVR-5525 for a Media PC that I'm building. But for some reason I can't seem to get the card working under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I followed the instructions [here][1] and can get the DVB-T and the DVB-C tuners to work. However the card also has a satellite tuner and no matter what I can't seem to get it working. I installed the firmware files under /lib/firmware, but somehow the tuner doesn't get recognized.
In fact even the card itself was not recognized until i created a .conf file under /etc/modeprobe.d telling the system what card it is using:

```
options cx23885 card=52
```

because otherwise nothing would happen and under dmesg it would just say

> unknown hauppauge model #150339

Here is what the dmesg output looks like now(cut out any unimportant stuff):

```
[    5.478658] tveeprom: Hauppauge model 150339, rev C6I6, serial# 40########
[    5.478665] tveeprom: MAC address is 00:##:##:##:##:##
[    5.478667] tveeprom: tuner model is SiLabs Si2157 (idx 186, type 4)
[    5.478668] tveeprom: TV standards PAL(B/G) PAL(I) SECAM(L/L') PAL(D/D1/K) ATSC/DVB Digital (eeprom 0xf4)
[    5.478670] tveeprom: audio processor is CX23888 (idx 40)
[    5.478671] tveeprom: decoder processor is CX23888 (idx 34)
[    5.478672] tveeprom: has radio, has IR receiver, has no IR transmitter
[    5.478673] cx23885: cx23885[0]: warning: unknown hauppauge model #150339
[    5.478675] cx23885: cx23885[0]: hauppauge eeprom: model=150339

[    5.644995] cx25840 9-0044: cx23888 A/V decoder found @ 0x88 (cx23885[0])
[    6.695716] cx25840 9-0044: loaded v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw firmware (16382 bytes)

[    7.443658] cx23885: cx23885[0]: registered device video0 [v4l2]
[    7.446938] cx23885: cx23885[0]: registered device vbi0
[    7.450921] cx23885: cx23885[0]: alsa: registered ALSA audio device
[    7.450925] cx23885: cx23885_dvb_register() allocating 1 frontend(s)
[    7.450928] cx23885: cx23885[0]: cx23885 based dvb card
[    7.451504] m88ds3103 7-0069: Unknown device. Chip_id=71
[    7.451796] cx23885: cx23885[0]: frontend initialization failed
[    7.452061] cx23885: cx23885_dvb_register() dvb_register failed err = -22
[    7.452327] cx23885: cx23885_dev_setup() Failed to register dvb adapters on VID_B
[    7.452595] cx23885: cx23885_dvb_register() allocating 1 frontend(s)
[    7.452598] cx23885: cx23885[0]: cx23885 based dvb card
[    7.502717] i2c i2c-7: Added multiplexed i2c bus 10
[    7.502724] si2168 7-0064: Silicon Labs Si2168-D60 successfully identified
[    7.502727] si2168 7-0064: firmware version: D 6.0.1
[    7.518854] si2157 8-0060: Silicon Labs Si2157 successfully attached
[    7.518995] dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (cx23885[0])
[    7.518999] cx23885 0000:04:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Silicon Labs Si2168)...
[    7.527300] cx23885: cx23885_dev_checkrevision() Hardware revision = 0xd0
[    7.527310] cx23885: cx23885[0]/0: found at 0000:04:00.0, rev: 4, irq: 17, latency: 0, mmio: 0xf7200000
[    7.974954] loop16: detected capacity change from 0 to 8

[   12.818647] si2168 7-0064: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw'
[   13.152287] si2168 7-0064: firmware version: D 6.0.2
[   13.155300] cx23885 0000:04:00.0: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 frequency 0 out of range (48000000..870000000)
[   13.164024] si2168 7-0064: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw'
[   13.498660] si2168 7-0064: firmware version: D 6.0.2
```

Interesting to me is that it appears (?) to use the wrong driver?;

> [    7.451504] m88ds3103 7-0069: Unknown device. Chip_id=71

According to every source I could find it should actually be a M88RS6000 tuner and not a M88DS3103.
I found an output from someone else where the correct module loads:

```
cx23885: cx23885_dvb_register() allocating 1 frontend(s)
cx23885: cx23885[0]: cx23885 based dvb card
a8293 10-000b: Allegro A8293 SEC successfully attached
m88rs6000t 13-0021: Montage M88RS6000 internal tuner successfully identified
dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (cx23885[0])
cx23885 0000:02:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Montage Technology M88RS6000)...
cx23885: cx23885_dev_checkrevision() Hardware revision = 0xd0
```

So somehow apparently it doesn't get recognized correctly?
Does anybody know how to fix this? I need the satellite function as well, so I'm kind of stuck right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since I have the same issue with the same card (mine is revision C5I6 though) I would be interessted in a solution as well.
What I found out untill now is that there were multiple revisions of the card which switched the eeprom model number from 150329 to 150339.
Since this new model ID is not found in cx23885 autodetect is not possible and you need the modeprobe.d file.
Also the subsystem in cx23885 turned from 0070:f038 to 0070:f039
Sadly it seems the Chip ID for m88ds3103 also switched from 64 to 71 which probably is the reason m88rs6000t isn`t loaded.
In an extract from linuxtv.org for this card you can see the old values:

```
[   14.471581] CORE cx23885[0]: subsystem: 0070:f038, board: Hauppauge WinTV-HVR5525 [card=52,autodetected]
[   14.803585] tveeprom 3-0050: Hauppauge model 150329, rev C3I6, serial# 4035814105
[   14.803589] tveeprom 3-0050: MAC address is 00:0d:fe:8d:a2:d9
[   14.803592] tveeprom 3-0050: tuner model is SiLabs Si2157 (idx 186, type 4)
[   14.803594] tveeprom 3-0050: TV standards PAL(B/G) PAL(I) SECAM(L/L') PAL(D/D1/K) ATSC/DVB Digital (eeprom 0xf4)
[   14.803596] tveeprom 3-0050: audio processor is CX23888 (idx 40)
[   14.803598] tveeprom 3-0050: decoder processor is CX23888 (idx 34)
[   14.803600] tveeprom 3-0050: has radio, has IR receiver, has no IR transmitter
[   14.803601] cx23885[0]: hauppauge eeprom: model=150329
[   14.803604] cx23885_dvb_register() allocating 1 frontend(s)
[   14.803606] cx23885[0]: cx23885 based dvb card
[   14.807030] i2c i2c-3: Added multiplexed i2c bus 6
[   14.872564] a8293 3-000b: Allegro A8293 SEC successfully attached
[   15.014407] m88rs6000t 6-0021: chip_id=64
[   15.086092] m88rs6000t 6-0021: Montage M88RS6000 internal tuner successfully identified
[   15.086105] DVB: registering new adapter (cx23885[0])
[   15.086110] cx23885 0000:03:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Montage Technology M88RS6000)...
```

To make the satellite part of this card work my guess is that cx23885 and/or m88ds3103 need to be updated with the current model ID (150339) and subsystem (0070:f039) and Chip_id (71) for this revision of the WinTV-HVR-5525.
If anyone has an idea who these values could be forwarded to, to get these kernel files updated please let us know.
Hauppauge also updated their WIN Software to make these revisions work as you can see in the change log WinTV v10.0.41115
https://www.hauppauge.com/pages/support/wintv10_release_notes.html